# How can I add a protected method to a class implementing an interface in java?

Tags: java, interface, wrapper

I have a class called `Property` which has nothing but `get`-methods. All the fields will be set when a new instance of `Property`is created. `Property` implements an interface called `IProperty`.

Due to some bug in a library I use, I have to set the name of an instance of `Property` anew  after its creation. Therefore it was suggested to create a `WrapperProperty`class that will provide a public `setName`-method which itself calls a therefore created `setName()`-method in `Property`, which will be protected/package view.

The problem is that I cannot make this method protected in `Property`, because Eclipse tells me to add it to the interface `IProperty` and make it public.

Is there some work-around to it?

**WrapperIProperty:**

```
public class WrapperIProperty {

    private IProperty prop;

    WrapperIProperty(Property prop) {
        this.prop = prop;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        prop.setName(name);
    }
}
```

**Property:**

```
public class Property implements IProperty {

    String name;

    protected void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int getFoobar() {
        return 123;
    }
    public int getWhatever() {
        return 987;
    }
}
```

**IProperty:**

```
public interface IProperty {

    public int getWhatever();
    public int getFoobar();
    public String getName();

}
```

This is how it looks at the moment. Obviously it won't work, since I cannot let the method be protected in the `Property` class. Therefore I best get rid of the interfacee entry somehow. But how?

Comment: Could we possibly get some of the code? It would make answering your question much easier.

Comment: If your Property class is not implementing IProperty  interface you can make method setName as protected.

Comment: Also, I don't think the constructor of `WrapperIProperty` will work.

Comment: my mistake.. didnt copy it right. forgot to add implements

Comment: Oh never mind, without the interface implementation I was confused.

Comment: you want to use a variable outside the class scope, then why you want to make it protected? in short you want to use a public property but want to make it protected..

Comment: @mtariq this is a design question. There should be no setter method at all in this class, only getters. But sincee there is a bug in the library I use I have to make a work-around as long as they didn't fix it. And for this reason I need a temporary setName method which should not public accessible. Only the wrapper should have access to it, because the wrapper will be deleted after the bugfix anyway.

Comment: The examples you provide indicate that your `Property` always has a public `setName` method since it implements IProperty. But you claim that `setName` is only temporary. What's going on here?

Comment: I had added it to the interface in the example to show the conflict, to clarify my problem. That seems to lead to misunderstandings, so I will remove it now. Point taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to do is to leave the `IProperty` interface alone (don't add the `setName` method to it) and create a delegating wrapper class which provides the method you want (wraps an implementation of the interface).

This way you can feed wrapped properties and regular properties to whatever needs them.

```java
public class WrappedProperty implements IProperty {

    private String name;

    private Property prop;

    WrappedProperty (Property prop) {
        this.prop = prop;
    }

    protected void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getWhatever() {
        return prop.getWhatever();
    }
    public int getFoobar() {
        return prop.getFoobar();
    }    
    public String getName() {
        if (this.name == null) {
           return prop.getName():
        } else {
            return this.name; 
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class Property implements IProperty {        

    public String getName() {
        return "blah";
    }
    public int getFoobar() {
        return 123;
    }
    public int getWhatever() {
        return 987;
    }
}
```

```java
public interface IProperty {

    public int getWhatever();
    public int getFoobar();
    public String getName();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods in an `Interface` are public in scope so implementing class cannot override methods by reducing their accessibility. Make them `public`

Comment: My question was whether there is a way to remove it from the interface _and_ let it be protected in the class.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a public *methodName* in an Interface and a private or protected *methodName* in a Class implementing this Interface.

So you can have the *methodName* public in your Class :

- this method do nothing
- this method call *[another]methodNameProtected* (you give another name to a new protected method)

**UPDATE**

If you want it only in Interface you have to change your Interface in an AbstractClass and put in it the method 
 *public final returnCode methodName* if the method is common for all inherited classes

Comment: well, this does not really solve the problem since I would also have a public method in `Property` that would change the name. The only place where I want the `setName` method to be public is the `WrapperIProperty` class.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to that problem:

**WrapperIProperty :**

```
public class WrapperIProperty {

    private Property prop;

    public WrapperIProperty(IProperty prop) {
        this.prop = (Property) prop;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        prop.setName(name);
    }

}
```

**Property:**

```
public class Property implements IProperty {

    private String name = null;

    [...]

    void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**IProperty:**

```
public interface IProperty {

    [...]
}
```

This will do the job